# Supplying options with an association

Tags: options, associations

Let's say I have an association, like `{"PlotStyle" -> Red}`, and I want to use it to supply options to a function, such as `Plot`. (Something like `**kwargs` in Python.) How do I do this? For context, I am writing some code that switches between using `Minimize` and `NMinimize` and need to only supply certain options in one of the two cases (in particular, `EvaluationMonitor`).

Comment: `"PlotStyle"->Red` would be a rule. Associations have a different syntax. Also in Mathematica, `PlotStyle` is a reserved symbol not a string. Do you want to use an alternate set of options for two different commands?

Comment: `{"PlotStyle" -> Red}` is not an association. That being said, you can pass options to most functions as a list. Try this `Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, {"PlotStyle" -> Red}]`

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started, 1) take the introductory [tour](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: There is one important difference between options stored as a list or sequence of rules, and options stored in an association. In a situation with duplicate options (same option names, different values), in the former case, the first value wins, while in the latter, the last value wins. This has to do with how lists of rules are applied, and how associations work. I was bitten by this a few times in exactly this setting.

Comment: **To the closers:** This sounds like a perfectly valid question to me (at least as formulated in text, when a real assoc is used - and since the OP mentions Python's `**kwargs`, they obviously meant assocs, not lists of rules - despite the code they provide), and the one having a subtlety I have mentioned in comment above, that is IMO worth an answer / discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
options = {ImageSize -> 400, PlotTheme -> "Web", PlotLabel -> "Test"};
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Evaluate@options]
```

[image]

Comment: If the options are given in a bona fide association, like this `assoc = <|ImageSize -> 400, PlotTheme -> "Web", PlotLabel -> "Test"|>;`  then  `Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}, Evaluate@Normal@assoc]`.